# Finding the sum of a "counter" variable loop that ran ten times then was pushed into the "numbers" array. Each way I tried resulted with a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm asking for help to find the sum of an array with elements that were pushed from a counter variable that had previously looped 10 times. I'm new to Javascript and was practicing for an assessment, and I've tried several different ways to do it and have only resulted with just a list of the elements within the numbers array.

```js
var counter = 10;
var numbers = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i ++) {
  counter = [i + 73];
  numbers.push(counter);
}

console.log(numbers);

function sum(arr) {
  var s = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     s = s += arr[i];
  }
  return s;
}

console.log(sum([numbers]));

function getArraySum(a) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i in a) {
    total += a[i];
  }
  return total;
}

var numbers = getArraySum([numbers]);
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: Did you not realise that putting a variable inside square brackets, as you do almost everywhere here, makes an array with that variable as its only element? Remove most of the square brackets - eg `counter = i + 73` in the first loop - and most or all of your problems should go away.

Comment: What Robin says. What you're probably mixing up is an array (`[someValue]`) with an index notation (`myObject[key]` or `myArray[0]`)..

Comment: @RobinZigmond ahh, I see! removing those brackets makes a total difference! Thanks for the input and help!

Answer (score 1):

you should push only the value of counter without the brackets and then make a reduce to have the sum of each number in the array

```js
var counter = 10;
var numbers = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  counter = i + 73;
  numbers.push(counter);
}

console.log(numbers.reduce((a,b) => a+b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of typos in the code:

###### Typos

1. You were wrapping the sum in square brackets:

```
counter = [i + 73];
```

You should just remove the brackets like:

```
counter = i + 73;
```

2.  You were wrapping a value that is already an array in square brackets while passing it as an argument to a function:

```
sum( [numbers] )

// ...

getArraySum( [numbers] );
```

You should remove the brackets, like this:

```
sum( numbers );

// ...

getArraySum( numbers );
```

###### Fix

I updated the code that you shared to fix the above-mentioned things:

```
var numbers = [];

// Loop 10 times and push each number to the numbers array
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i ++) {
  var sumNumbers = i + 73;
  numbers.push(sumNumbers);
}


console.log(numbers);


function sum(arr) {
  var total = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     total += arr[i];
  }

  return total;
}

// Call the function by passing it the variable numbers, holding an array
var result1 = sum(numbers);
console.log( result1 );



function getArraySum(a) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i in a) {
    total += a[i];
  }
  return total;
}

var result2 = getArraySum(numbers);
console.log(result2);
```